# if updated cache manifest, will browser download ALL images again?

Tags: html, offline-caching, cache-manifest

If I change the cache manifest, will the browser be smart enough to keep the image files it already has from previous version of the manifest or will it scrap everything and start from zero when downloading the new offline stuff?

It's kind of important since I might have 50mb worth of images. This is a digital signage solution where I have control over the clients so storage limits will not be a problem. What I am considering though is to solve it in a different way than the html5 offline cache, perhaps some rsync solution on the mediaplayers behind the scenes..

Comment: To determine if the cached resources have changed, the browser will ask your server for them. It is up to your server to respond with `304 Not Modified` if they haven't. See [the specification on how the cache download algorithm works](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#downloading-or-updating-an-application-cache), specifically step 17 in the algorithm.

Comment: So it will in fact find out on an each file basis before downloading resources anew? So I would be safe using the cache manifest even for larger amounts of data?

Comment: Provided your server responds with the right headers and the client implements the specification correctly, yes, you should be fine.